# Show custom View issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]
[image: output image]

when I click on button I get only 1 extra view, but I want a the view to be added dynamically on number of click, (like for loop)...Kindly help me with this code, **Thanks in Advance**,
this is just a part of my code

```
if (boolVal == true) {
    CGRect newFrameC = CGRectMake(_centreView.frame.origin.x, _centreView.frame.origin.y, _centreView.frame.size.width, 50);
    CGRect newFrameL1 = CGRectMake(_label2.frame.origin.x, _label2.frame.origin.y+50, _label2.frame.size.width, 50);
    _centreView.frame = newFrameC;
    _label2.frame = newFrameL1;
    boolVal = false;
}else if (boolVal == false){
    CGRect newFrameC = CGRectMake(_centreView.frame.origin.x, _centreView.frame.origin.y, _centreView.frame.size.width, 1);
    CGRect newFrameL1 = CGRectMake(_label2.frame.origin.x, _label2.frame.origin.y-50, _label2.frame.size.width, 50);
    _centreView.frame = newFrameC;
    _label2.frame = newFrameL1;
    boolVal = true;
}
```

Comment: you want add serial view on background view?

Comment: What issue are you facing ? frame is not setting properly or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

**DummyViewController.m**

```
#import "DummyViewController.h"
#import "ExtraView.h"

@interface DummyViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) unsigned int numberOfExtraViews;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray<ExtraView*>* extraViews;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel* label1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel* label2;

@end

@implementation DummyViewController

-(void) removeExtraViews{
    for (ExtraView* extraView in _extraViews){
        [extraView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [_extraViews removeAllObjects];
}

-(CGRect) getExtraViewFrame{
    CGRect extraViewFrame = _label1.frame;
    if (_numberOfExtraViews > 0) {
        extraViewFrame = [_extraViews lastObject].frame;
    }
    extraViewFrame.origin.x += extraViewFrame.size.height;
    return extraViewFrame;
}

- (void) addExtraViews{
    //[self removeExtraViews];
    int numberOfExtraViewsToDraw = _numberOfExtraViews - _extraViews.count;

    for (int iterator = 0; iterator < numberOfExtraViewsToDraw; iterator ++){
        CGRect extraViewFrame = [self getExtraViewFrame];
        ExtraView *extraView = [[ExtraView alloc]initWithFrame:extraViewFrame];
        [self.view addSubview:extraView];
        [_extraViews addObject:extraView];
    }

    if (numberOfExtraViewsToDraw > 0) {
        CGRect label2Frame = [_extraViews lastObject].frame;
        label2Frame.origin.x += label2Frame.size.height;
        _label2.frame = label2Frame;
    }

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self addExtraViews];
    //rest of your code
}

//Use this code in initWithNib/initWithCoder. Don't copy paste the same
-(instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (nil != self){
        _numberOfExtraViews = 0;
        _extraViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}

//the function that gets hit when the button is tapped.
- (void) onButtonTap{
    _numberOfExtraViews++;
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

**Note the following:**

1. I do not understand what the boolVal is, but if it keeps toggling upon the click of the button, you'll never have multiple views.I assumed it toggles, so I havent used it at all.
2. Use the init code in initWithNib/initWithCoder. Don't copy paste the same. Don't overwrite the given code. Just append to your current init.
3. In my code onButtonTap is the function that gets hit when the button is tapped.
4. I've done it by ensuring viewDidLoad method gets hit agin. But I dont think it's necessary. You can also do this:

   ```
   //the function that gets hit when the button is tapped.
   - (void) onButtonTap{
       _numberOfExtraViews++;
       [self addExtraViews];
   }
   ```

**What has been done:**

1. Let me call what you call as centerView as extraView. There will be many extraViews, so I'll create an array for the same (extraViews).
2. The count of the number of views is stored in numberOfExtraViews. Initiated to 0 in init.
3. Whenever the button is tapped, we increase the count and call view's setNeedsDisplay, which in turn hits the viewDidLoad method
4. In viewDidLoad, we add the extraViews.